# unix command zip everything except file ending with _fpartxx

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, zip

I was wondering, if I have a folder structure like this:

```
/var/www/testing/file1.iso_fpart0
/var/www/testing/file1.iso_fpart1
/var/www/testing/file1.iso_fpart2
/var/www/testing/file1.iso
/var/www/testing/file2.xls_fpart0
/var/www/testing/file2.xls
```

how can I run zip command, zip everything except file ending with _fpartNumber.
I only know this command,

```
zip -r total.zip .
```

Comment: Surely you must be aware of the commands `zip --help` and `man zip` too

Comment: You might try posting this at unix.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: @Harts I've updated my answer to show a wildcard for the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
zip -r foo foo -x \*.o
```

which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that end in .o.

Comment: x command option is for excluding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name "*_fpart*" -print | zip total.zip -@
```